# Correct use of and/or symbols?

Tags: notation

In for example equation sets, is it correct/normal to write "$x=0 \wedge y=3 \vee x=3 \wedge y=-6$"? or finding zeroes in a function "$x=3 \wedge x=6$"?

Comment: I would say that it's much more usual to use "and" and "or".

Comment: Agree with saulspatz. Also, you may want to use brackets if you're so keen on writing in such notation.

Comment: I would use parentheses since $P\wedge Q\vee R\wedge S$ is ambiguous whether you mean $((P\wedge Q)\vee R)\wedge S$ or if you mean something else.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you. Do you write like this or do you just write "and/or", or something else?

Comment: I would more often see the question phrased in a specific way such as "Find the set of all solutions in $\Bbb R^2$ to the system of equations" to which the answer would be of the form $\{(0,3),(3,-6)\}$.  Alternatively, I would see it written as "If $(x,y)$ is a solution to the system of equations then $(x,y)=(0,3)$ or $(x,y)=(3,-6)$"  Sometimes people will shorthand this as $(x,y)=(0,3)$ or $(3,-6)$.  Alternatively you could use set notation again as $(x,y)\in\{(0,3),(3,-6)\}$

Comment: @JMoravitz That looks much better, I agree. Forgot to ask, when would you use these symbols?

Comment: Personally, I rarely do, but I normally see it in use for [propositional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) or when writing rigorous definitions such as $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definitions in calculus.  Using the words "and" and "or" use up a little extra space but it often helps readability.  Too many symbols clumped up together can become hard to parse for myself and in my experience several other people.